# How to make the code not end after inputing 1 number?

Tags: python

```
import random
x = random.randint(0,50)

if int(input()) == x:
    print ("yes")
else:
    print ("no")
```

I want to make a guessing game, but I don't want the number to reset after 1 guess.

Comment: This is an *extremely*  basic question. Please work through a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to get an overview of the features available in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `while` loop:

```
import random
x = random.randint(0,50)

while int(input("Enter a number: ")) != x:
    print ("No! Try again.")
else:
    print("Yes!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
x = random.randint(0,50) 
incorrect = True

while incorrect: 
    if int(input()) == x: 
        print ("yes") 
        incorrect = False 
    else: print ("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that allows you to exit the loop at will:

```
import random
x = random.randint(0,50)
guess = None
while guess != -1:
    guess = int(input("Enter a guess or -1 to exit: "))
    if guess == x:
        print ("yes")
        break
    else:
        print ("no")
```